# I want to catch error when throwing error using switchMap

Tags: angular, typescript

I got problem when trying to catch error when using `switchMap()`. 
I want to make a checking every single api either data is already exist or not.

This is my code

```
public signupform(userData: SignupRequest): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.post('api/auth/createorganisation')
    .pipe
    (tap( // Log the result or error
      data => {
        if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.') {

      switchMap(() => this.http.post('api/auth/createuser')
       .pipe(
        catchError((error) => this.handleError(error))
        )
      )

        }else{
          throw new Error(data.status['message']);

        }
      }
    )
    )
  }

  error: boolean;
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    this.error = true;
    console.log(error)
    return empty();
  }
```

Hope you all can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask your IDE to format and indent your code properly, and you'll see that you call switchMap inside the callback passed to the tap() operator, instead of calling it as an argument of pipe().

Answer (score 0):

You are using `switchMap` inside `tap` which is not correct. You need to move `switchMap` before/after (based on your need) the `tap` operator like following (in this example, you don't need `tap` operator btw):

```
public signupform(userData: SignupRequest): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.post('api/auth/createorganisation')
     .pipe(             
         switchMap((<any>data) => {
               if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.') {
                    return this.http.post('api/auth/createuser').pipe(
                      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error))
                    );
                }else{
                   throw new Error(data.status['message']);
               }
          })
       )
   )
}

error: boolean;
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  this.error = true;
  console.log(error)
  return empty();
}
```

---

Hope this helps.

For further reading:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got error at `data.status` . it said Property 'status' does not exist on type 'unknown'. And .`pipe` .it said Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, Object>'

Comment: You can do type casting like `switchMap((<any>data) => {...})` or whatever the reponse type you want instead of `any`. And please replace second `pipe` from `switchMap` to `http.post` (it's my bad).

Comment: it come out another error. Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: What is the console ouput of `data`?

Comment: output `console.log(data)` is `[object Object]`